# Using Python's inspect library to check if a dynamically named function exists

Tags: python, function

I'm running a python program (Python 2.7.5) that calls functions dynamically using the eval method. I need to find out if the function exists -before- I do any of the prerequisite calculations needed to run it if it does exist.

To do this, I've been trying to employ the inspect python library, which uses inspect.isfunction(foo). However it cannot take in dynamically named functions as a string to determine if the function exists.

```
import inspect

for i in range(1, 4):
    if inspect.isfunction("hello" + i):
        print("Function does exist")
    else:
        print("Does not exist")

def hello1():
    print("Hello")

def hello3():
    print("Hello2")
```

At the moment it is not returning the correct boolean value as to whether or not the function exists. Is there any way of converting "hello" + 1 to the function itself (hello1 instead of "hello1")

Comment: If you have the option, stop creating variable names dynamically and store the functions in a `dict` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try` block :

```py
try:
    hello1
except NameError:
    print("The function does not exist")
else:
    print("The function exist")
```

Comment: A good solution, but as the function is dynamically named, the name of the function is stored as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get, if possible, the object bound to the *name* in the current scope.

```
if inspect.isfunction(globals().get('hello{}'.format(i))):
```

If `hello1` is defined, the call to `get` will return the object bound to that name, and `isfunction` can determine if it is, indeed, a function.

If it is not defined, `get` returns `None`, for which `isfunction` will return `False`.